# Unable to start pulse in Gemfire 9 after using ServerLauncher

Tags: java, gemfire, pulse

I am trying to run Gemfire Server using java code. However, I am unable to start pulse as I get an error saying "geode-web-api war file was not found".

There are no logs printing after this:

> [info 2020/02/11 14:32:46.648 GMT  tid=0x1]
>   GEODE_HOME:C:\FAST\pivotal-gemfire-9.9.0
>
> [warn 2020/02/11 14:32:46.649 GMT  tid=0x1] geode-web-api war
>   file was not found
>
> [info 2020/02/11 14:32:46.649 GMT  tid=0x1] Unable to find
>   GemFire Developer REST API WAR file; the Developer REST Interface for
>   GemFire will not be accessible.
>
> [info 2020/02/11 14:32:46.650 GMT  tid=0x1] Initializing region
>   **ParameterizedQueries**
>
> [info 2020/02/11 14:32:46.650 GMT  tid=0x1] Initialization of
>   region **ParameterizedQueries** completed

Here is the code I am using to run the ServerLauncher:

```
public static void run(String cacheFile, String locator,
                           boolean enableJmx, String jmxPort, String httpPort, String locators) throws Exception {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(cacheFile) || StringUtils.isEmpty(locator)) {
            throw new Exception("Could not start Gemfire for configFile " + cacheFile + " and locator " + locator);
        }
        if (enableJmx && StringUtils.isEmpty(jmxPort)) {
            throw new Exception("jmxPort not specified");
        }
        ServerLauncher serverLauncher = new ServerLauncher.Builder()
                .set("cache-xml-file", cacheFile)
                .set("start-locator", locator)
                .set("jmx-manager", "" + enableJmx)
                .set("jmx-manager-start", "true")
                .set("log-level", "debug")
                .set("jmx-manager-port", jmxPort)
                .set("http-service-bind-address", "localhost")
                .set("http-service-port", httpPort)
                .set("jmx-manager-update-rate", "2000")
                .set("start-dev-rest-api", "true")
//                .set("locators", locators)
                .build();
        serverLauncher.start();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Although started in a similar fashion, the `geode-web-api` is unrelated to Pulse. However you may see similar logging messages, related to Pulse in the event that the Pulse war also cannot be found. Can you check that the war file exists in `${GEODE_HOME}/tools/Pulse`.

Comment: Yes it is located in that folder. I see what you mean by geode-web-api is unrelated to Pulse. Is there a way to start pulse without the `.set("start-dev-rest-api", "true")`. As I don't see any log related to pulse starting up through Jetty.

Comment: Sorry, I completely missed that you're starting up a Server. Pulse is only started as part of the Locator startup. In order to use Pulse you would need a Locator.

Comment: I see. I have tried to launch a locator but get the following error:

Comment: `GEODE_HOME:C:\FAST\pivotal-gemfire-9.9.0. geode-web war file was not found. Unable to find Geode V1 Management REST API WAR file; the Management REST Interface for Geode will not be accessible. geode-pulse war file was not found. Unable to find Pulse web application WAR file; Pulse for Geode will not be accessible`

Comment: I am not sure why it is not able to find the jars in that folder, even though they are there

Comment: Have you tried adding the `war` file to your application classpath?, that seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried the following locally (as a quick example) and it works fine:

```
public class TestLocator {
    static {
        System.setProperty("gemfire.home", "/apps/pivotal-gemfire-9.9.1");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocatorLauncher launcher = new LocatorLauncher.Builder()
                .set("jmx-manager", "true")
                .set("jmx-manager-start", "true")
                .set("log-level", "config")
                .set("log-file", "/test/locator.log")
                .set("http-service-bind-address", "localhost")
                .set("http-service-port", "7070")
                .build();
        launcher.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which dependencies did you use for this? Did you include the Jetty dependencies or should it pick it up form the jar files from the gemfire.home path?

Comment: I can't find the example project locally, probably deleted it a while ago... :-S. If my memory doesn't fail me, I manually added the `jetty` dependencies found within the `/lib` folder.